# Displaying all x axis labels; not just ones where a point value exists

Tags: android, achartengine

I'ms setting custom text labels on my line chart, using this on the renderer:

```
String[] xLabelsForTimeScale = getXLabelsForCurrentTimeScale(); //weekday names

        for (int i = 0; i < xLabelsForTimeScale.length; i++)
            {
            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, xLabelsForTimeScale[i]);

            }
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGridX(true);
```

when the chart renders, it's only displaying x labels for points where I have a non null series value. For example, assume that the xLabelsForTimeScale array is an array of weekday abbreviations. If I have only two values, say for Mon, Tue, it only shows labels for Mon and Tue. I'd like to display all the x axis labels, whether there's a series point or not. Sun - Sat, basically. How can I do that?

ADDITIONAL INFO ON REQUIREMENT: I don't want to add zero, dummy points within the series if I can at all help it. What I expect to happen is the line just renders between actual points, connecting each actual, valid point, in a linear fashion. If I add zero, dummy points, there will be a lot of pointy tops (lack of a better term) as the line draws between valid point data, and placeholder, dummy data. Hope that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You can add whatever custom label you want. So, nothing stops you from adding random labels at points that do not exist in the chart.

Comment: @DanI'm already adding the x axis labels; the problem is, if there's no corresponding value in the series for the x, it's not displayed. That's what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: @wkhatch wherever u want label u have to add .

Comment: @keshav I am adding them... the problem is, they do NOT show up if there's no corresponding value for that point in the series. I'm working around it by creating a junk series that has zero values for each of the points, which then forces the entire range to be rendered, and not just the parts with values.

Comment: @wkhatch if there is not a value that means it is not added then how it will appear ? Either u add it manually .

Comment: @keshav, I'm talking about the x axis labels; they don't appear if there's no corresponding point in the series. If I have a set of labels for days of week, I want to see the entire week represented, whether there's points for any specific day or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this for time charts by calling:

```
renderer.setXRoundedLabels(false);
```